# Number field when empty and value=0

Tags: field, fieldtypes, number

Is there a way to differentiate the number field value empty and 0?

I would like to display this field only when there's a value in the field even though the value is 0.

But when I input 0 into the field, it seems that Craft thinks the value is empty... so doesn't still display the field.

Thanks.

Comment: Where are you trying to display the field value? Twig has the [`empty` test](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tests/empty.html) which may be of interest!

Answer (score 1):

Twig's `is not null` should work for this.  Assuming you have a Number field called `number` and you're looping through a list of entries, something like this should work:

```
{% for entry in entries if entry.number is not null %}
    {{ entry.number }}
{% endfor %}
```